# How to combine Eclipse Databinding and UndoableOperations?

Tags: eclipse, data-binding, eclipse-rcp, undo-redo

in my RCP - Project i'm using eclipse databinding to connect the ui with the backend. I want every change in an open editor to be undoable. My Domainmodell and UI are seperated in two different plugins.

My current approach is to implement my own UpdateValueStrategy class for the databinding. I extend the normal UpdateValueStrategy and override the doSet Methode.

From there i get the OperationHistory and the Global UndoContext, then i create a new Operation. I have various Operations like "ChangeCustomerName" and "ChangeCustomerNote".

Questions:

1. Do i need to implement the undo/redo - logic by my own, or is the framework somehow supporting my with this?
2. Is there a better place or way to create the undoable Operation then the doSet() of the UpdateValue - Strategy class. To access the textfield, which was changed is not to easy.

Answer (score 2):

The answer you will get mostly is: Use [EMF.Edit](http://help.eclipse.org/helios/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.emf.doc/references/overview/EMF.Edit.html), it includes it out of the box with org.eclipse.emf.databinding.edit and there's an excellent [tutorial](http://tomsondev.bestsolution.at/2009/06/06/galileo-improved-emf-databinding-support/) on the net.

There is an open [feature request](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=116465) in the Eclipse bugtracker about including undo/redo also in JFace databinding without EMF but it's not finished yet. It has also be discussed in the [eclipse forum](http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php?t=msg&&th=154022&goto=485335).